# Theorem for independent and symmetrically distributed random variables.

Tags: statistics, operations-research

I trying to understand the following proof. My main difficulty is understanding the transformations from Eq. 14 to Eq. 15, specially the step after the integration.

Can someone help me?

This theorem is from Bertsimas, D., & Sim, M. (2004). The price of robustness. Operations research, 52(1), 35-53.

https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.1030.0065?journalCode=opre

Thank you in advance.

[image: Proof - Theorem 2]

Comment: The integration $2\int_0^1 \eta_{ij}^{2k}dF_{\eta_{ij}}(\eta_{ij})$ is just the expected value of the random variable $\eta_{ij}$. Since this random variable is supported on $[-1,1]$, this expectation is at most $1$. This explains the first inequality. The second follows by expanding $\exp(\theta^2\gamma_{i,j}^2/2)$ into its Maclaurin series and noting the $k^\text{th}$ term is $(\theta\gamma_{i,j})^{2k}/(2^k\cdot k!)$, which is more than $(\theta\gamma_{i,j})^{2k}/((2k)!)$

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much, Mike!